# c# WebApi Post request end point with json body returns server error 500

Tags: c#, json, post, webapi, httpwebresponse

I have a project where i need to pass JSON body. But whenever i try passing that i get ""The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error." when GetRespose() is called in this line.
**var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();**

But when i trigger the same from PostMan it is working fine.

Not sure if the Json tag formatting is right or is the format feasible.

Also The webapi is hosted on an Ubuntu server in nginx web server and i am calling this from c# code.

Not sure what i am missing and how to solve this.

Here is my code:

```
var url = "https://vb01.vbtest.in/paymentinfo";
var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";

httpRequest.Accept = "application/json";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";


var data = @"{
"TID": "3123",
        "RefID": "777",
        "PaymentInfo": {
            "ClientName": "abc123",
            "ClNo": "F123-7",
            "Name": "George",
            "City": "Ind"
        },
        "PaymentDetails": {
            "Part1": "Sept",
            "Part2": "Oct",
            "Part3": "Oct2"
        },
        "CreditsUsed": "2"
        }";
        httpRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(data);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(httpResponse.StatusCode);
```

Comment: Why there is extra double like "", try removing those extra double quotes.

Comment: Check headers, that are sent via Postman - server may require `Content-Length` header to be set, so you may need to add `httpRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;` before writing to request stream.

Comment: @Amit: I have modified the tag to remove extra double quotes but still not working

Comment: @Quercus: I did add Content-Length but still not working. Have edited the post with this attribute as well.

Comment: I would recommend you to use some HTTP-capture tool, like Fiddler or WireShark to see what HTTP requests are actually sent from PostMan and from your application.